# kitkat usb connection problem

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

my galaxy grand 2 cannot connect the sd card of usb storage to computer. only 2 options are available with usb
namely
media device
camera
how can I access the files of sd card and usb storage

Please note that Im using Ubuntu 14.04

I have no problems with windows

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 seems to have some issues with MTP working correctly. You need to install the mtpfs and make sure the phone usb connection is set to MTP to work.

See the Ubunto syack exchange for more info. https://askubuntu.com/questions/463015/ubuntu-14-04-and-android-cant-see-phone-on-my-computer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable information. Sorry to say but it didnt work. Then I installed Qlix and some other libraries for MTP. Now its ok. I can connect the phone memory and sd card to Ubuntu 14.04 and can transfer files from and to the PC.

Comment: Since its about Ubuntu 14.04 which is the recent LTS release from Canonical, could you mention the names of the libraries (version no. will be too good) and the steps that you followed to download and install them? That would make it a completely useful answer with everything(except libraries) available here.

Answer (score 0):

In synaptic I searched MTP. It listed programs and libraries related libraries. From those I installed Qlux, mtpfs and some other libraries (I coudnt give the exact details for now since Im away from home & codnt have my laptop). After installation connected my phone and opened Qlix. It searched for MTP devices and found my phone(both card and phone dtorage). Try this. Best of luck